# permalink in wordpress give page not found

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

hi everybody i have an error in my wordpress that i cannot fix. i would like to install wp with buddypress so permalink are necessary.
so .htaccess is editable by wp:

```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
   </IfModule>
   # END WordPress
```

mod_rewrite is present in phpinfo()
do not know what to do...
any suggestion?

Comment: the web site is http://simulazionediborsa.eu

Comment: Go to your settings page for permalinks and click Save, they may have to be flushed.

Comment: i did but stil the result is a broken link.

Comment: Without any other information or having access to the site it's difficult to determine what's wrong with the permalinks. If you'd like send me a message and i'll help by email http://bit.ly/UHR2WS

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem adding

```
 <Directory />     
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    ...
```

to httpd-vhosts.conf
under the tag